# Microsoft SQL server to select Top N group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

There are a lot of answers about how to select n rows from each group.
But what I am looking for is to select every row from top N group, for example I have the data below:

```
 id   group
  1     a
  2     a
  3     b
  4     c
  5     c
  6     d
  7     d
  .......
```

If I want to select Top 3 Group, my intended results as below:

```
   1    a
   2    a
   3    b
   4    c
   5    c
```

How can I achieve this with Microsoft SQL server 2008?

Comment: Note: Do not use [reserved keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) `group`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use a subquery which selects the top N groups:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.group
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP(N) group
    FROM yourTable
    ORDER BY group
) t2
    ON t1.group = t2.group
```

Comment: Shouldn't ORDER BY be replaced with GROUP BY

Comment: @TheShooter I am using `DISTINCT` to find the first `N` groups.  An alternative would be to use `GROUP BY` without `DISTINCT`.

Comment: Agreed. Shouldn't have missed that :(

Comment: Thanks for the guidance @TimBiegeleisen :)

Answer (score 1):

You could [`rank`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) your rows by the group and then take only the top three:

```
SELECT [id], [group]
FROM   (SELECT [id], [group], RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [group] ASC) rk
        FROM   mytable) t
WHERE  rk <= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

@Tim: I just modified your query.

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.group
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT TOP N group
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY group
    --ORDER BY group USE IT IF YOU WANT
) t2
    ON t1.group = t2.group
```